# yii booster checkbox doesn't show boxes to check

Tags: checkbox, yii, yii-booster

I add the checkbox functionality from the [yii-booster](http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/extended-grid.html). But the widget renders the model view without the needed boxes. What's wrong?

**Widjet code in view**

```
<?php
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbExtendedGridView',array(
'id'=>'docs-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'type'=>'bordered condensed',
'template' => "{items}",
'bulkActions' => array(
    'actionButtons' => array(
        array(
                'buttonType' => 'button',
                'type' => 'primary',
                'size' => 'small',
                'label' => 'Choose',
                'click' => 'js:function(values){console.log(values);}'
                )
            ),
            // if grid doesn't have a checkbox column type, it will attach
            // one and this configuration will be part of it
        'checkBoxColumnConfig' => array(
        'name' => 'id'
        ), 
  ),    
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem has been in the wrong hierarchy from the example:
The 'checkBoxColumnConfig' attribute must be *outside* of the 'actionButtons' attribute:

```
'bulkActions' => array(
    'actionButtons' => array(
        /*array(
                'buttonType' => 'button',
                'type' => 'primary',
                'size' => 'small',
                'label' => 'Выбрать отмеченные',
                'click' => 'js:function(values){console.log(values);}'
                )
            ),*/
            // if grid doesn't have a checkbox column type, it will attach
            // one and this configuration will be part of it

    ), 
    'checkBoxColumnConfig' => array(
        'name' => 'id'
        ), 
...
));
```

but now the widget doesn't work when i uncomment the array part inside 'actionButtons':

```
 array(
                'buttonType' => 'button',
                'type' => 'primary',
                'size' => 'small',
                'label' => 'Выбрать отмеченные',
                'click' => 'js:function(values){console.log(values);}'
                )
```

what might be a cause?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bulkActions, you have to use 'columns' to list out the columns you want to display instead of using 'template'.

```
'columns' => array(
    'id',
    'title', 
    ...
),
```

Comment: if i do not attribute `'columns'` the widget loads all the columns of the dataProvider.